# Shader's layout position versus accessor id of GLTF file

Tags: three.js, glsl, gltf

I am using three.js with Webgl2 to show a gltf file I made for GIS purpose.
I need a custom vertex attribute as gltf allows that.
The shader compiles OK in GLSL 300 es

The thematics are in vertex attribute buffer interleaved with the position.

Everything draw ok. But now I want to use the thematic data .
If I define the layout at location 2  like the accessors

```c
layout(location=2) in  uint thematic;
```

Everything still draw ok if I dont use the variable. But if I do, 
I got error like this

[.WebGL-000000000BAE32A0] GL_INVALID_OPERATION: Vertex shader input type does not match the type of the bound vertex attribute.

What is the right way to declare the layout for a custom vertex attribute??

Finally I decide to use a prdefined attribute, namely COLOR_0, and it works.

Here is the primitive declaration in the gltf and the accessor

{ "attributes" : { 
   "POSITION" : 1 , 
  "COLOR_0":2 },

{ 
 "bufferView" : 1,
 "byteOffset" : 12, 
 "componentType" : 5121, 
 "count" : 16263,
 "type" : "VEC3", 
 "normalized" :  true 
}

Component Type 5121 stand for unsigned byte (should be normalized)

Populating with random color I got that image

[image]

But This is just à workaround and a bad one using 32 bits where I need only 4. I need 16 bits for record gid and the rest for outline and bacground styling

Does any one know how To teach 3js's gltfLoader and shader compiler to expose custom vertex attributes so we can reference and use it normaly?

======================================================

Following ScieCode's suggestion I sent a report to 3js forum and Michael Herzog told me that glVertexAttribIPointer is not yet supported but he will work on it.

[3JS Add support for integer attributes with WebGL2](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/19019)

Comment: How are you populating the thematic data? Are you sure the provided Interleaved Buffer is using the correct data type ( Int32 ) ? GL is complaining about incorrect attribute type.

Comment: I populate the thematic in the same C++ loop as the vertex position, using uint32 ; Now if I polulate it with float [0 199] and declare the layout as float, GL does NOT complain but the thematic is NOT accessed properly and seem to be 0 filled. I might be with three.js not using glVertexAttribIPointer –

Comment: Shot in the dark here, but remove `layout(location=2)`. Leave just `in uint thematic;` and see if it changes anything.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and the attribute is recognized but GL complains: Vertex shader input type does not match the type of the bound vertex attribute.

My gltf:

 "attributes" : { 
   "POSITION" : 1 , 
  "_THEMATIC":2 }, 

and the accessors

   { 
 "bufferView" : 1,
 "byteOffset" : 12, 
 "componentType" : 5125, 
 "count" : 16263,   
 "type" : "SCALAR" 
 }

Comment: That's indeed really weird, as the `componentType: 5125` does match `UnsignedInt` type. Consider making a post on https://discourse.threejs.org/, including detailed description of the problem and possibly the gltf file. This could be an internal problem with Three.js.